# Getting area of pentagon with some values missing

Tags: geometry, area

I have a problem how to get the area from the picture.
Some ideas I got are not good enough to get the correct value of the whole element.

[image]

Comment: This post would be much improved if you include the ideas you had, and where they failed!

Comment: The ordinary word for a convex polygon of five vertices is *pentagon*. The word you’ve used is usually reserved for another kind of five-vertex figure.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Draw straight lines between the upper left corner and the midline, and upper right corner and the midline. Now you have two rectangles and two triangles. Can you compute their areas?

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have enough data to compute the area (if 13.62 denotes the lenght of the basis as it seems on the OP figure). The area depends on the « balance » between the left and the right sides of the house. And this seems unknown from your picture.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But since those different lengths of the sides is an anomaly I decided to accept that the tip is in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: You know the width is $13.62$, and the maximum height it reaches is $1.65$, so it must fit within a rectangle of those dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I asked someone and this answer will satisfy me

[image]